# How to see the sum of all context switches of all threads within a Java process?

Tags: java, linux, performance, monitoring, pid

I am running pidstat on CentOS linux to monitor a Java application. When I feed the java pid to pidstat it never shows any context switches.

```
top
2407 root      20   0 7939m 4.2g  11m S 129.3 58.4 138:47.08 java

pidstat -w -I -p 2407 3

09:53:41 AM       PID   cswch/s nvcswch/s  Command
09:53:44 AM      2407      0.00      0.00  java
```

I have to find the pid of a specific Java thread (using top -H) to see the context switches.

```
top -H
2915 root      20   0 7939m 4.2g  11m R 22.8 58.3  17:36.93 java

pidstat -w -I -p 2915 3

09:53:41 AM       PID   cswch/s nvcswch/s  Command
10:10:11 AM      2915    643.67    230.33  java
```

How can you see the sum of all context switches of all threads within a Java process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to do this in Java, then the API doesn't provide such means. You will have to resort to a platform dependent way of doing this.

You could perhaps use JNI/JNA to do this natively for different operating systems:

- Windows - [Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373083%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- Linux - [getrusage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage)

---

If you mean to do this with pidstat, then you should really ask this question in [SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/). However, as far as I know you can add `-t` to your `pidstat` command, so that it looks like so:

```
pidstat -w -I -t -p <pid> 3
```

It will list stats for all the threads of the process.

Comment: I want to do this using pidstat or other command line tools. The -t option is great: I am piping it to awk to sum it up like: `pidstat -w -I -t -p <pid> | awk '{ sum += $5 } END { print sum}'` unfortunately that way you cannot refresh like pidstat does but ok